# Get a string inside a string

Tags: c#, string, numbers, sequence

```
string a = "100-0-6-7-6-10-8-" //and so on

/////////////////////////////////////////////
//my solution

char[] delimiterChars = {'-'};

    string solution = "100-0-6-7-6-10-8-";
    string[] words = solution.Split(delimiterChars,System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

//ok so i encounter some problems when trying to overwrite 0s, and 10s,100s etc
//so when writing data to the "solution" string it should be 
//"-100--0--6--7--6--10--8-" instead of "100-0-6-7-6-10-8-"
```

basically, I want to separate each number and put it in a list or array

Comment: From what you listed above, it sounds like you have the right thought process - where did you get stuck? It's best to help from where you left off on what has been tried.

Comment: Hint: instead of "separate" the numbers, think "split" the string. See if that gives you what you need :)

Comment: `var result = a.Split("-");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i got it

```
    char[] delimiterChars = {'-'};

    string text = "100-0-6-7-6-10-8-";
    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars,System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution using Linq works as well.

```
var text="100-0-6-7-6-10-8-";
var words=text.Split("-").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```